# SQL LIMIT doesn't work as excepted

Tags: mysql, sql

I always thought that `LIMIT` in a query selects only between numbers I set.

Suppose I have two columns to be selected with primary key - id. I have 90 rows.

```
SELECT name, lastname 
FROM some_table 
WHERE id = '123' LIMIT 0, 30
```

will select exactly 30 rows. Ok, but

```
SELECT name, lastname 
FROM some_table 
WHERE id = '123' LIMIT 30, 60
```

will select more than 30 rows. Well, I am doing this for AJAX paginator using PHP+mysql.

How can I do this right way?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you working on?

Comment: mysql with php for server side

Answer (score 9, accepted):

limit is offset, rowcount. so it should be limit 30,30, not 30, 60, if you want 30 rows.

Comment: Well, thanks! But I am talking about next 30 rows. For example, firs page has first 30 rows, the next page has next 30 rows and so on

Comment: Yeah, so it would be select ... limit (p -1 )*30, 30 for your query where p = 1,2,3, ... so that you get 30 rows each time. i think in your original query you assumed it was start, end, which they are not.

Comment: It is still not working for me. `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY highscore DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5` and `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY highscore DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10` returning the same result. And they are different than the records when i omit the LIMIT clause!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM some_table WHERE id = '123' LIMIT 30, 30;
```

In simple language,

First 30 is the starting record number
Second 30 is the 30+30 which is 60th record.

This should work to get the records between 30 and 60.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify two arguments to `LIMIT`, the second one is the maximum number of rows to return; so instead of `LIMIT 30, 60`, write `LIMIT 30, 30`. (See [the explanation of `LIMIT` in §12.2.9 "SELECT Syntax" of the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#id1023306).)

Answer (score 2):

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

second parameter is row count.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

```
LIMIT 30 -- get 30 records
LIMIT 30, 60 -- skip 30 records and get next 60
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), the second number of the limit statement is the number of rows to be returned.  If you want to get rows 31-60, then you need to specify

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM some_table WHERE id = '123' LIMIT 30, 30
```

You're asking MySQL to give you 60 rows start at offset 30.